# Paginated reports in PowerBI outdated?

Tags: powerbi

I guess, there are several opinions regarding the usage of PBI Desktop and paginated reports, but I thought it worth a try.

In our company we are using Desktop reports as well as paginated reports, the latter mainly for list reports concerning operative data. Now some would like to stop the usage of pagniated altogether, because they are of the opinion, this is an old-fashioned technology and everything should be handled via Desktop. From my point of view there are legitimate reasons for the usage of list reports - sometimes you just need the details and Desktop has its strengths mainly concerning more of a top level view. To me this has nothing to do with outdated.

What are your opinions, how do you handle these two tools or are there other setups you would recommend?

Comment: [When to use paginated reports in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/report-paginated-or-power-bi)